# How to assign a value outside the callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, callback

I'm developing a web application with Angular 4 (using TypeScript / JavaScript language). 
Unfortunately I don't know JavaScript  and its callback mechanism very well.
I have a problem. If I call a method that takes a function as a parameter, such this:

```
    this.cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params,function(err,data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
       else {
         console.log(data);      
    }
```

I can use the `data` parameter only inside the body of `function(err,data)` and not elsewhere.

If I initialize an external object inside `function(err,data)`, it seems that the object only takes the right value within the function, but 
not externally, as in this example:

```
var myData = null; // external variable declaration

this.cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params,function(err,data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
   else {
     myData = data;
     console.log(myData); // prints the date value (correctly)  
}
console.log(myData); // print 'null' but I would like the data of 'data' object
```

I would be very comfortable with using this data outside `function(err,data)` to pass them as a parameter. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. You would either have to wrap your callback in a promise and the access it in a .then() or pass the variable using a callback. You can't expect it to access it synchronously when asynchronous code is present You can use the code

```
function PromiseWrapped(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)){
        this.cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params,function(err,data) {
           if (err) reject(err)
           else {
             resolve(data);
        }
    }
}

PromiseWrapped().then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example of code? I do not know the mechanism of synchronous and asynchronous JavaScript calls

Comment: check out the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: thanks, but the example is too long and I can't make it match with my situation because my method listUser takes two input parameters and not just the function! 
If you wrote me how I can customize my code you would do me a favor!

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Give me an error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'cognitoIdentityServiceProvider' of undefined

Comment: check the scope of this, I'm pretty sure you're referring to the wrong this

Comment: I don't explain why the property 'this' appears to be unknown in this scope!

Comment: Try printing what this refers to

Comment: It prints the properties of my class if I use console.log(this) outside the function written by you; 
otherwise print undefined (if i use console.log(this) in the scope of function PromiseWrapped() )

Comment: You can pass this as an argument in your case, in a variable called that

Comment: Ok, it works, but the problem persists. How do I use the "data" object outside of the body of "PromiseWrapped().then(function(data)" ?

I would like to use it to assign it to a data field or return it to another class, but I can not!

Comment: If you want the code to act synchronously, you can't. You can update inside the .then() and then use it in subsequent .then() functions